# How fast does a black hole appear to decay from infalling observer's perspective?

Tags: black-holes

Black holes eventually decay by emitting radiation. It can take a long time. But from an outsider's perspective.

How long does it take from the perspective of someone falling into it?

I understand that time passes faster for someone closer to it, so would the rate at which it decays also appear to speed up?

Could it be so fast that the person falling into it sees it decay before it even reaches the surface?

[image]

Comment: For starters someone falling into a black hole, won't be falling for very long even from their point of view. The decay rate _may_ appear to increase, but I don't expect it's significant relative to the time you can spend between crossing the horizon and being destroyed / flung elsewhere (reaching the singularity in any case).